# Can I "GROUP BY" a partial field value in Access/SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, ms-access-2016

In Access/SQL, I know I can `GROUP BY` ,say, `country` or `age`.

Can I also `GROUP BY` partial value, for example, field start with something like `"G"` or `"18"`, so that `"Germany"` and `"Ghana"` are in one group, `"1897"` and `"1870"` are in one group?

Comment: You can do `GROUP BY LEFT(country, 1)` but you can't have `country` in the output since there is no way to aggregate multiple `"G"` countries into a single field in your output. Perhaps share some sample data and your desired results and we can offer more help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by any non-aggregate expression. E.g.:

```
SELECT   LEFT(country, 1), COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY LEFT(country, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MID()` or `LEFT()` along with `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select mid(country,1,1), count(*)
from table t
group by mid(country,1,1); -- or with left (country,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select group_concat(country), count(*) as count
from employees
group by left(country,1)
```

i think this should solve

Answer looks like

```
India, Indonesia 2
America, Australia, Argentina 3
```

Comment: oh I understood it wrongly that "/" i thought he may asking about access or SQL